# Application defined or object defined error 1004 and Error 438 in using vlookup formula

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vlookup, application-error, vba

I am trying to use the vlookup function on a range of cells, that looks up values in other sheets. However I ckeep getting a runtime error that says "application defined or object defined error."

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1", Selection.End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, _
    Header:=xlYes
'In Summary Tab
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
nRows = Selection.Rows.Count

' Places column headers in "Summary" tab
For iCounter = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(iCounter).Select
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select
    nCols = Selection.Columns.Count
         For iColumn = 2 To nCols
            Sheets(iCounter).Select
                If (WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(2, iColumn)) = "TRUE") Then
                Cells(1, iColumn).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Summary").Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                ActiveCell.Resize(nRows - 1, 1).Select
                Selection.Formula = "=vlookup(B2," & _
                    Range(sheets(icounter).selection).Address","& icolumn",false)"
                End If
        Next
Next
```

I also tried editing the vlookup formula to this, (with everything else the same):

```
                Selection = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                    "B2", Sheets(iCounter).CurrentRegion.Select, iColumn, False)
```

But this gives error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

Even tried editing the vlookup to this but got the 1004 error again:

Selection = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("B2",Sheets(iCounter).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nCols, nRows)), iColumn, False)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if you're attempting to insert formulas into certain ranges. `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` doesn't insert a formula, it's used to return a value to your sub/function just like a normal function would do. So your top example is the correct approach if the goal is to insert a bunch of formulas.

The reason you're seeing an error on that line of code is because you aren't actually referencing a range. Try this instead:

```
Selection.Formula = "=vlookup(B2," & Sheets(icounter).Name & "!" & _
                        Selection.Address & "," & icolumn & ",false)"
```

Notice that this code calls out the name of the sheet, adds the exclamation point (`!`) and then adds the address of the selection.

You may also have been seeing errors because you were missing a few ampersands (`&`) in your code.

Finally, please beware of using `.Select`, `.Selection`, and `.Activate`. They have their place in VBA, but they will create many headaches for you. For more information on how to avoid using `.Select`, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/2200824) by Chris Neilsen and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10718179/2200824) by Siddharth Rout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution and explanation, this piece of code worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
On error resume next
```

At the top of your script. If vlookup doesn't find a match, it will return an error.

If it returns an error, your script stops.

Your current & last proposals are essentially the same with different syntax - but I don't think that's the cause of your problem. Try on error next instead.

Comment: If the OP intends to insert formulas into a range, using `Resume Next` here doesn't actually fix the issue...